# Removing Value from Array when Deselect Cell

Tags: uitableview, swift

I'm trying to remove a particular item in the array `selectedFoodTypes` if a user deselects a row. However, I keep running into the error:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
    let deselectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!
    selectedFoodTypes = selectedFoodTypes.filter {$0 != deselectedCell.textLabel!.text!}
    println(selectedFoodTypes)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling `let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()`

The `indexPath` parameter of the function gives you the `indexPath` of the deselected row.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let deselectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!
    selectedFoodTypes = selectedFoodTypes.filter {$0 != deselectedCell.textLabel!.text!}
    println(selectedFoodTypes)
}
```

The above code might work. But comparing with `textLabel.text` of the cell is not a good idea. If `datasourceArray` is an array for example and set as the tableView `dataSource`, you can do

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let deselectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!
    selectedFoodTypes = selectedFoodTypes.filter {$0 != datasourceArray[indexPath.row]}
    println(selectedFoodTypes)
}
```

Comment: The problem is I need the array to contain the string values of each row. Since I'm allowing multiple selections, users might select the rows out of order. Thus, converting from indexPath.row to the corresponding string becomes difficult

Comment: what is the `datasource` for the tableview? maybe its better to do it like i have shown above.

Comment: Let me try your code. it is a UITableViewController